# How to improve the performance of adding a range to a ListView

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, performance, listview

I have a simple data-bound list of elements in my WPF application that I am trying to squeeze more performance out of. In the code below, I add a million records and signal a change in my list of items.

I have the following XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Log_.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Log+ Viewer" Height="400" Width="500">
    <Grid Name="MainGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="Everything">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding LogRecords}">
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Message" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Message}"/>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Timestamp" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Timestamp}"/>
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is the C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Log_
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public ObservableList<LogRecord> LogRecords { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LogRecords = new ObservableList<LogRecord>();
            DataContext = this;
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                LogRecord record = new LogRecord();
                record.Message = "Hello, world.";
                record.Timestamp = DateTime.Now;
                List<LogRecord> logRecordList = new List<LogRecord>();
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
                {
                    logRecordList.Add(record);
                }
                Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
                timer.Start();
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    LogRecords.AddRange(logRecordList);
                });
                timer.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("The operation took {0} milliseconds.", timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            }).Start();
        }

        public class LogRecord
        {
            public string Message { get; set; }
            public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
        }

        public class ObservableList<T> : IEnumerable<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged
        {

            public List<T> UnderlyingList = new List<T>();

            public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

            public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> list)
            {
                UnderlyingList.AddRange(list);
                OnCollectionChange(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, UnderlyingList));
            }

            protected virtual void OnCollectionChange(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (CollectionChanged != null)
                {
                    CollectionChanged(this, e);
                }
            }

            public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
            {
                return UnderlyingList.GetEnumerator();
            }

            System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
            {
                return UnderlyingList.GetEnumerator();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output is: "The operation took 4834 milliseconds."

This seems like an absurd amount of time for it to be adding these records in as a range of records. Am I breaking UI virtualization here because my items source inherits IEnumerable like this or is this normal performance? How can I get this code to run much faster than it currently does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that, indeed, I think inheriting the enumerable was a very bad idea, whereas I should have gone with just the ObservableCollection...consider the performance difference:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Log_
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public ObservableList<LogRecord> LogRecords { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LogRecords = new ObservableList<LogRecord>();
            DataContext = this;
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                LogRecord record = new LogRecord();
                record.Message = "Hello, world.";
                record.Timestamp = DateTime.Now;
                List<LogRecord> logRecordList = new List<LogRecord>();
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
                {
                    logRecordList.Add(record);
                }
                Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
                timer.Start();
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    LogRecords.AddRange(logRecordList);
                });
                timer.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("The operation took {0} milliseconds.", timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            }).Start();
        }

        public class LogRecord
        {
            public string Message { get; set; }
            public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
        }

        public class ObservableList<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
        {

            public override event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

            public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> list)
            {
                foreach (var item in list)
                {
                    Items.Add(item);
                }
                OnCollectionChange(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
            }

            protected virtual void OnCollectionChange(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (CollectionChanged != null)
                {
                    CollectionChanged(this, e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The operation took 75 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a million records you probably don't want to update the UI with all of those records.  Consider using paging or loading records in the grid view as the user scrolls through the list.

Comment: But doesn't the ListView incorporate UI virtualization, so that it only displays the records it needs to display by default, and because of this, should it not handle this behavior already, especially considering the fact that I am only signaling it to update once because of the logic in the ObservableList...unless, of course, inheriting the IEnumerable is causing it to signal multiple times...?

Comment: Did you enable deferred scrolling?  ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"

Comment: Jake, I found a solution...I think inheriting the IEnumerable was indeed a bad idea...I'll post it now. Please check it out, but note it doesn't have anything to do with the ScrollViewer with deferred scrolling enabled.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is probably using a local variable to store and latter assigning it to the `LogRecords` Property..

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //A local variable
    var logRecords = new ObservableList<LogRecord>();
    DataContext = this;
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        LogRecord record = new LogRecord();
        record.Message = "Hello, world.";
        record.Timestamp = DateTime.Now;
        List<LogRecord> logRecordList = new List<LogRecord>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            logRecordList.Add(record);
        }
        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            // Should prevent UI to update itself
            logRecords .AddRange(logRecordList);
        });
        timer.Stop();

        // Assign to actual collection causing UI update
        LogRecords = logRecords ;    
        Console.WriteLine("The operation took {0} milliseconds.", timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    }).Start();
}
```

Comment: Yes. AddRange should operate on the local variable rather than the actual collection .